# Cloudfoundry: Docker app crashes on startup

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

When I try to start up my docker image, it crashes on startup because it exceeds some quota.

Is there any way to increase said quota?

Log:

```
"exit_description"=>"failed to create container: running image plugin create: pulling the image: streaming blob `sha256:e627f246588031563fb0a8ec26f6b275f92f97bd3b150376f2afdb571b0a1d1e`: writing blob to tempfile: uncompressed layer size exceeds quota\n: exit status 1", "crash_count"=>1, "crash_timestamp"=>1540365703889102250, "version"=>"d8e21bbc-385d-4d41-b921-0c627ccd4a95"
```

Docker image:
https://hub.docker.com/r/gabac/docker-python-opencv-flask_web/

Thanks
Cyril

Comment: have you tried using a larger disk quota?

Comment: stupid me...works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that your docker image is larger than the default disk limit. You can increase the disk limit when you push your docker image by specifying the parameter `-k`. E.g.:

`cf push -k 2G`

If you're using a manifest to specify the parameters please add the following code to your manifest.yml

`disk_quota: 2G`

Comment: The output of `docker images` shows the uncompressed size of your docker image, you need to set `-k` to be larger than that value.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the disk limit did the trick

cf push --help:

```
   -k                           Disk limit (e.g. 256M, 1024M, 1G)
```

Comment: Adding additional details will help future developers, who are having the same problem, quickly solve the issue. Maybe a screenshot of the place you update the settings or a list of steps for updating it? Thanks!